# Reading a file of number into an array while skipping first two values every 1026 entries

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

I am trying to read in a text file of numbers in which there are 2 values in the beginning that I do not care about, followed by 1024 values that I do care about. The file has approximately 100000 entries that I need to do a calculation on every 1024 of them. The format is something like

1

1025

3000

3572

3579

4023

3593

2930

.

.

.

1

1025

.

.

.

So basically the 1 and the 1025 are header values describing the data set which I need to ignore, then I need to read every value after those header values into an array so I can then run calculations on the values in the array. I was thinking of using while(!file.eof()) but I can not think of how to have the code skip those two numbers while it reads through the 100000 entries. I am pretty new to c++, I usually use GUI's to do my data analysis, but I am on a project that is requiring me to us C++, so I'm really out of my comfort zone here. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Have you created that file? If so, consider writing your data in a binary format instead of a text file.

Comment: Perhaps you might count the sequence, then use a switch statement - i.e. "switch (seqNum)" with no action on "case 0" or "case 1";  do your calculation in the switch's "default" selection.  etc.    But this seems very fragile.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, SO is not a "write this for me" kind of site. Please try something and ask about concrete errors you receive, or specific programming problems.

Comment: Is each entry in your file on a line by itself, followed by a blank line?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can do it. The most straight forward example I could think of was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  std::string s;
  while( std::cin >> s )
  {
    if( i++ < 2 ) continue;
    std::cout << s;
    if( i == 1024 ) i = 0;
  }
}
```